# Is there a way in eclipse to change the alignment of parenthesis of all methods, loops, if statements, etc. at once?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on a Java project where code was written by different programmers. There are about 50 packages with 1-10 classes per package.

In some code, the methods and if statements, for example, are declared as follows -

```
public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

if(value==0) { 
   System.out.println("value is 0");
}
```

And in other code, the methods and if statements, for example, are declared as follows-

```
public void setValue(int value)
{
   this.value = value;
}

if(value==0) 
{ 
   System.out.println("value is 0");
}
```

The difference is in the **alignment of parenthesis**. Is it possible in Eclipse to at once change all of the former types of alignments into the latter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First configure the Formatter:

```
Window / Preferences / Java / Code Style / Formatter
```

Then apply the format to a class selecting the code and doing:

```
Ctrl + Shift + F
```

You can do it over all classes in a package or source folder doing right click over the element and selecting:

```
Source / Format
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! Really saved me lot of time!

Comment: You can right click on a Java project as well to format all source folders in the project.

Answer (score 2):

Once you configure the formatting settings, you can Format one class, a whole package, or an entire project. Just right-click on the class/package/project and choose Source > Format.

Be aware, however, that doing so will apply *all* formatting rules to the code, not just the parentheses settings.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is possible in IntelliJ. A quick Google search yields this [document](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Default-Format-Settings-in-Eclipse). I believe it is what you are looking for.